# ce:chem tag to be converted to mml:math

Tags: xslt, tags, converters

Is there a way to convert these elsevier tags into mml:math tags?

```
<ce:chem>PEG<ce:inf>BOUND</ce:inf>
<ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>=<ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>PEG<ce:inf>TOT</ce:inf>
<ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>-<ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>PEG<ce:inf>FINAL</ce:inf>
</ce:chem>
```

Comment: Not aware of any existing conversion code but wanted to point out that [The Elsevier DTD 5 Family of XML DTDs](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/58409/ja50_tagbytag5-v1.1.pdf) includes both the `ce:chem` elements you list and MathML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**XML:** (Ensure `ce:chem` content should not have line breaks and comment text. `grouping` functions can do better than my code, but I placed this jsut to meet the requirement)

```
<article xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd"
xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<p>
<ce:chem>PEG<ce:inf>BOUND</ce:inf><ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>=<ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>PEG<ce:inf>TOT</ce:inf><ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>-<ce:hsp sp="0.25"/>PEG<ce:inf>FINAL</ce:inf>A<ce:sup>2</ce:sup></ce:chem>
</p>
</article>
```

**XSLT 2.0:** (latest xslt)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd"
xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
xmlns:ja="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ja/dtd">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ce:chem">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ce:inf)][not(self::ce:sup)] | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="ksub" match="ce:inf" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()])"/>
<xsl:key name="ksup" match="ce:sup" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()])"/>

<xsl:template match="ce:chem/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::node()[1][name()='ce:inf']">
            <xsl:element name="ce:msub">
                <xsl:call-template name="tempNameElements"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ksub', generate-id())" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::node()[1][name()='ce:sup']">
            <xsl:element name="ce:msup">
                <xsl:call-template name="tempNameElements"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ksup', generate-id())" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="tempNameElements"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ce:hsp">
    <xsl:element name="mml:mspace">
        <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="@sp"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ce:inf">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:call-template name="tempNameElements"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ce:sup">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:call-template name="tempNameElements"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tempNameElements">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(replace(self::text(), '([A-z]+)', 'A'), 'A')">
            <xsl:element name="mml:mi"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(replace(self::text(), '([0-9]+)', '9'), '9')">
            <xsl:element name="mml:mn"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(self::text(), '^(\(|\[|\{|=|\-)$')">
            <xsl:element name="mml:mo"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:element name="mml:mtext"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd"
     xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <p>
   <ce:chem>
     <ce:msub>
        <mml:mi>PEG</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>BOUND</mml:mi>
     </ce:msub>
     <mml:mspace width="0.25"/>
     <mml:mo>=</mml:mo>
     <mml:mspace width="0.25"/>
     <ce:msub>
        <mml:mi>PEG</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>TOT</mml:mi>
     </ce:msub>
     <mml:mspace width="0.25"/>
     <mml:mo>-</mml:mo>
     <mml:mspace width="0.25"/>
     <ce:msub>
        <mml:mi>PEG</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>FINAL</mml:mi>
     </ce:msub>
     <ce:msup>
        <mml:mi>A</mml:mi>
        <mml:mn>2</mml:mn>
     </ce:msup>
  </ce:chem>
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you Rudramuni! This actually work but the disable-output-escaping="yes"> does not convert the &lt; into '<'.